# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Alguien sabe como resolver este error en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, json, listview, adapter

```
**

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando seleccione un elemento de la lista "Gamas" que me actualice la listview de Normas.
 
La primera vez lo hace bien pero al seleccionar de nuevo el mismo u otro elemento de la lista, la aplicación se cierra y salta el error.
```

No sé si habría que insertar por aquí esta línea de código:
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Por favor, necesito ayuda con esto. gracias.

Dejaré. algunas fotos para que se entienda mejor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Intenté usar esto también pero no me funcionó: **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**
Este es el siguiente error que me sale:


E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. **




public class Gamas_Normas_View extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> BrandList;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
   static TextView idOT;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gamas_normas);


        idOT =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.idOT);
        Bundle  bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        String valor_recibido2 = bundle.getString("ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO");
        idOT.setText(valor_recibido2);




        BrandList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGamas);
        ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNormas);




        new Gamas_Normas_View.GetGamas(Gamas_Normas_View.this,lv).execute("http://localhost/service1.svc/consGamas/"+idOT.getText().toString());

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);

               Gamas_Normas_View.GetNormas(Gamas_Normas_View.this,lv2).execute("http://localhost/service1.svc/consNormas/1");
               // lv2.invalidateViews();

            }
        });

    }
//Las Gamas ListView
    class GetGamas extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String status = null;
        Activity context;
        ListView lv;

        public GetGamas(Activity context, ListView lv) {
            this.context = context;
            this.lv =lv;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... connUrl) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                final URL url = new URL(connUrl[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int result = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (result == 200) {
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        status = line;


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return status;

        }
```

Esta es la lista de las gamas:

Alguna sugerencia?

Estoy haciendo algo mal? Faltaría adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String var0=object.getString("ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO");
                        String var = object.getString("INSTALACION");
                        String var2 = object.getString("DENO_GAMA");
                        String var3 = object.getString("PLANIFICADO");

                        String var4 = object.getString("ESTADO");
                        String var5 = object.getString("FABRICANTE");
                        String var6 = object.getString("MODELO");

                        String var7 = object.getString("FECHA_ULT_PREV");
                        String var8 = object.getString("FEC_NUEVA_REV");
                        String var9 = object.getString("ZONA_PRODUCCION");
                        String var10 = object.getString("UBICACION");





                        HashMap<String, String> itemList = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        itemList.put("ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO", var0);
                        itemList.put("INSTALACION", var);
                        itemList.put("DENO_GAMA", var2);
                        itemList.put("PLANIFICADO", var3);
                        itemList.put("ESTADO", var4);
                        itemList.put("FABRICANTE", var5);
                        itemList.put("MODELO", var6);

                        itemList.put("FECHA_ULT_PREV", var7);
                        itemList.put("FEC_NUEVA_REV", var8);
                        itemList.put("ZONA_PRODUCCION", var9);
                        itemList.put("UBICACION", var10);

                        BrandList.add(itemList);


                    }




                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Gamas_Normas_View.this, BrandList, R.layout.item_gama, new String[]{ "ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO","INSTALACION", "DENO_GAMA", "PLANIFICADO", "ESTADO", "FABRICANTE", "MODELO","FECHA_ULT_PREV", "FEC_NUEVA_REV", "ZONA_PRODUCCION", "UBICACION"}, new int[]{R.id.ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO, R.id.INSTALACION, R.id.DENOM_GAMA, R.id.PLANIFICADO, R.id.ESTADO, R.id.FABRICANTE, R.id.MODELO,  R.id.FECHA_ULT_REV, R.id.FECHA_NUEVA_REV, R.id.ZONA_PRODUCCION,R.id.UBICACION});


                    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) lv).setAdapter(adapter);
```

Es aquí donde iría adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();??

```
                    if (adapter.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(Gamas_Normas_View.this, "vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Gamas_Normas_View.this, "Por favor active la conexión VPN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }
```

La lista que debería actualizarse

```
//Las Normas ListView

    class GetNormas extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        String status = null;
        Activity context;
        ListView lv;

        public GetNormas(Activity context, ListView lv) {
            this.context = context;
            this.lv =lv;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... connUrl) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            BufferedReader reader;
            try {
                final URL url = new URL(connUrl[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                int result = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (result == 200) {
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        status = line;


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return status;

        }
```

Y esta será la segunda lista, la de las normas, que se tendría que actualizar cuando seleccione un elemento de la lista anterior

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String var0=object.getString("ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO_EQUIPO");
                        String var = object.getString("DESCRIPCION");
                        String var2 = object.getString("REALIZADO");
                        String var3 = object.getString("CORRECTO");

                        String var4 = object.getString("ID_TIPO_VAL_01");
                        String var5 = object.getString("VAL_PREV_01");
                        String var6 = object.getString("VAL_MED_01");

                        String var7 = object.getString("ID_TIPO_VAL_02");
                        String var8 = object.getString("VAL_PREV_02");
                        String var9 = object.getString("VAL_MED_02");
                        String var10 = object.getString("FECHA_ULT_PREV");
                        String var11 = object.getString("FRECUENCIA");





                        HashMap<String, String> itemList = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        itemList.put("ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO_EQUIPO", var0);
                        itemList.put("DESCRIPCION", var);
                        itemList.put("REALIZADO", var2);
                        itemList.put("CORRECTO", var3);
                        itemList.put("ID_TIPO_VAL_01", var4);
                        itemList.put("VAL_PREV_01", var5);
                        itemList.put("VAL_MED_01", var6);

                        itemList.put("ID_TIPO_VAL_02", var7);
                        itemList.put("VAL_PREV_02", var8);
                        itemList.put("VAL_MED_02", var9);
                        itemList.put("FECHA_ULT_PREV", var10);
                        itemList.put("FRECUENCIA", var11);
                        BrandList.add(itemList);


                    }




                    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Gamas_Normas_View.this, BrandList, R.layout.item_norma, new String[]{ "ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO_EQUIPO","DESCRIPCION", "REALIZADO", "CORRECTO", "ID_TIPO_VAL_01", "VAL_PREV_01", "VAL_MED_01","ID_TIPO_VAL_02", "VAL_PREV_02", "VAL_MED_02", "FECHA_ULT_PREV", "FRECUENCIA"}, new int[]{R.id.ID_ORDEN_TRABAJO_EQUIPO, R.id.DESCRIPCION, R.id.REALIZADO2, R.id.CORRECTO2, R.id.ID_TIPO_VAL_01, R.id.VAL_PREV_01, R.id.VAL_MED_01,  R.id.ID_TIPO_VAL_02, R.id.VAL_PREV_02, R.id.VAL_MED_02,R.id.FECHA_ULT_PREV, R.id.FRECUENCIA});


                    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) lv).setAdapter(adapter);




                    if (adapter.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(Gamas_Normas_View.this, "vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Gamas_Normas_View.this, "Por favor active la conexión VPN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy1Vt.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy3hf.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error:

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a
> notification

indica que se detecto los datos que alimentan el adapter fueron modificados pero no has realizado una notificación para su actualización.

Para notificar el cambio y tus datos se actualicen es precisamente como lo comentas, debes llamar el método [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()) :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Pero también obtienes el mensaje de error:

> Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a
> background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter
> calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. *

En el caso de un `SimpleAdapter` no puedes modificar su código para agregar `notifyDataSetChanged()` al recibir los datos, lo que debes realizar es notificar el cambio de datos en el método `onPostExecute()` de tu `Asynctask` (después de llamar `setAdapter()` ).

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            try {
                ...
                ...
                ...
                ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) lv).setAdapter(adapter);

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
          ...
          ...
          ...
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo, pero lo he intentado de esa manera también y me sigue dando el mismo error....